# Proper usage of pip from Docker

Tags: python, docker, pip

I want to install some packages with `pip` in a container. The trivial way to do this is the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install python-pip <lots-of-dependencies-needed-only-for-pip-install>
RUN pip install <some-packages>
```

However, this way I install a lot of unneeded dependencies, which increases the size of the container unnecessarily.

My first idea was to do this:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty AS pip_install
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install python-pip <lots-of-dependencies-needed-only-for-pip-install>
RUN pip install <some-packages>

FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install python-pip <runtime-dependencies>
COPY --from=pip_install /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=pip_install /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

This works, but feels like a workaround. Is there any more elegant way of doing this? I thought of something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty AS pip_install
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install python-pip <lots-of-dependencies-needed-only-for-pip-install>
RUN pip install <some-packages>
VOLUME /usr/local

FROM ubuntu:trusty
<somehow mount /usr/local from pip_install to /tmp/pip>
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install python-pip <runtime-dependencies>
RUN pip install <from /tmp/pip> <some-packages>
```

Is this even possible?

I could have used some of the `python` images, but in my real application I derive from another image that itself derives from `ubuntu:trusty`. As for this question, it's beside the point.

Comment: What about just uninstalling build-time dependencies with `apt-get` after building and installing Python packages with `pip`?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost That doesn't decrease the image size, as those files still exist in the lower layer.